# Prove that $\det Df\equiv 0$ if $g\circ f \equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

Let $f:R^n\to R^n$ be a smooth function and $g:R^n\to R$ $$g(x_1,\dots,g_n)=x_1^5+\dots+x_n^5$$ Assume that $g\circ f\equiv 0$. Prove that $\det Df\equiv 0$.

The only idea I have is to apply the chain rule $d(g\circ f)_p=dg_{f(p)}\cdot df_p$, where each term is the corresp. matrix of partial derivatives. Then since $g\circ f=0$, $d(g\circ f)_p=0$ for any $p$. But this doesn't imply that either of the two matrices on the RHS is zero. Is it still true that the determinant of one of them is zero? Why do we need the explicit form of $g$?

Comment: **HINT**: Think of this as a system of linear equations. Suppose that $Df(p)$ is nonsingular for some $p$, hence on some neighborhood of $p$. What does this tell you about $f$ on that neighborhood?

Comment: @TedShifrin Then $f$ is invertible on that neighborhood. Since $g\circ f = 0$ on the neighborhood, $g=0$ there. But on the other hand $g$ is given by a different formula. This looks like a contradiction. So $\det Df\equiv 0$.

Comment: How do you justify your statement that $g=0$ there? Why not use the specific formulas?

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought $g\circ f =0\implies g=g\circ f\circ f^{-1}=0\circ f^{-1}=0$. Is this a considered a specific formula?

Comment: But there are functions that are $0$ on an open set but not everywhere $0$. There is something going on here because $g$ is an explicit polynomial. What *is* $Dg_y$? If $Df_p$ is nonsingular, what do the chain rule equations tell you explicitly about $f(p)$?

Comment: I guess I should make my point more explicitly: How do you know for this *particular* function $g$ that one cannot have $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ in some nonempty open set?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, you mean that the polynomial in question may be identically zero on some set. For your further hint, $Dg_y=[5y_1^4,\dots,5y_n^4]$ if $y=(y_1,\dots, y_n)$. But if we use the chain rule, $y=f(x), x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and then $Dg_{f(x)}=[5f_1(x)^4D_1f_1(x),\dots ,5f_n(x)^4D_nf_n(x)]$. If $Df_x$ is invertible, then $Dg_{f(x)}$ is zero (if we use the assumption $g\circ f\equiv 0$).  So $f_i(x)^4D_if_i(x)=0$ for $i=1,\dots, n$. But does this help?

Comment: You are confusing $Dg_{f(x)}$ with the entire derivative. So if $Dg_{f(x)}$ is the $0$ map, this means that $f_1(x)^4 = f_2(x)^4 = \dots = f_n(x)^4=0$. What now?

Comment: @TedShifrin The entire derivative of what? Is my expression incorrect? I don't see why my espression and $Dg_{f(x)}$ implies what you wrote. According to my previous comment, it implies $f_i(x)^4D_if_i(x)=0$ for all $i$. It may be the case that $f_i\ne 0$ for all $i$ but $D_if_i(x)=0$ for all $i$. However, if $f_1(x)^4=\dots=f_n(x)^4=0$, then $f_1=\dots=f_n=0$, and $f$ is the zero map, so $Df\equiv 0$. But in this case I don't see a contradiction (which must emerge since we assumed the converse).

Comment: You need to step back and review the chain rule and the meaning of $Dg_y$ with $y=f(x)$. :) At any rate, yes, if you assume $Df_x$ is nonsingular for $x\in U$, you end up with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in U$, which is an obvious contradiction.

Comment: @TedShifrin $Dg_y$ is a map $R^n\to R$, so it corresponds to an $1\times n$ matrix. The element $a_{1j}$ of the matrix is the $j$th partial derivative of $g$ at $y$. So I guess $Dg_y$ should be just $5[f_1(x)^4,\dots,f_n(x)^4]$. (Previously I took the derivatives of $f_i(x)^4$ instead and used the one variable chain rule.) Then it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin Just to clarify, we don't need that $f$ is invertible in a neighborhood, we only need that $df_p$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $p$ (which follows from the continuity of $\det$)? So the only major result that's used here is the chain rule (and not e.g. the inverse function theorem as I supposed in my first comment)?

Comment: Right. Or you could use the implicit function theorem to show that, except for the origin, $g=0$ defines an $(n-1 )$-dimensional manifold, which, together with the origin, must contain the image of $f$.